# Visa for Spain: do I need to translate my passport?

Tags: visas, spain, translations, san-marino

I am applying for a visa for Spain. I gathered all the necessary documents and made them translate.
Now I have a doubt which I was not able to clarify reading the available information on the application process and this forum: do I also need to translate my passport (issued by San Marino, which is not in the EU, and with the personal information written in Italian, English and French)? What if it contains a visa stamp (from the UK, so in English)?

I already spent thousands so don’t want to waste more if not necessary. Thank you.

Comment: I am 99% sure that the answer is _no,_ but I will leave it to someone who is more certain than I to post an answer.

Comment: I am also sure that the answer is no, but it would be helpful if you clearly state in which language your passport is written in (or just which country issued the passport).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The passport was issued by San Marino and I wrote in which languages the personal information is provided in the main message.

Comment: In other words you are appling for a long term visa (> 3 months). A translation of your passport is not needed.

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled that you could spend thousands for a visa for Spain with a San Marino passport. What kind of visa are you applying for? What documentation did you need to get translated?

Comment: The legalized signature of the sworn translator alone was 150 without taxes. They requested something like 20 documents. I need a Visa since I am going to do my PhD there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Very likely no**, because almost all passports are bilingual, where English is secondary language. Especially those from countries with different alphabets (✔ [Israel](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Israel_Biometric_Passport.jpg), ✔ [Greece](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Greek_passport_biodata_page.png), ✔ [Ukraine](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ukrainian_biometric_passport_data_page.jpg), ❓ [China](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chinese_Service_E-Passport_Passport_Personal_Info_Page.jpg) ✔ [Japan](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ja_ic_passport.jpg)). I can't find a San Marino passport's biographical page picture.

To my record, it is only necessary to translate passports (with a bilingual stamp) to travel to certain **few** Arabian-speaking countries such as Lybia.

> What if it contains a visa stamp (from the UK, so in English)

Essentially **nothing**. Travel record has little to no weight in student visa applications compared to the ability to economically sustain yourself and criminal records (which are part of companion documentation). Every country you visit stamps foreign passports in their own language.

I believe you are overthinking this, but I understand you care a lot about your application. Should I be concerned about my `Бориспіль` stamp on my last page? (please let the OP guess before commenting)

Comment: [Images of a Sanmarinese passport are available](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/SMR-AO-02001/image-107474.html) from the EU's PRADO database, but the summary is that they're printed in Italian, English, and French, as the original question says.